# How i can read files in haskell?

Tags: haskell

Im beginner and im trying to read files from my folder "papers"(in the same path that the scripts), but i have the next error:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘[FilePath]’
                with actual type ‘IO [FilePath]’
    In the first argument of ‘leerDocumentos’, namely ‘pathFicheros’
    In the first argument of ‘return’, namely
      ‘(leerDocumentos pathFicheros)’
```

Maybe this is not the one error that i have on my code, so i hope that someone can help me to complete my module.

The code of my reader:

```
module LeerDocumentos2 where
import System.Directory
import System.IO.Unsafe
import System.IO()
import Documento


reader :: IO [Documento]
reader = do
    setCurrentDirectory "papers"
    directorio <- getCurrentDirectory
    putStrLn directorio       -- Directorio donde estan los documentos
    let pathFicheros = getDirectoryContents directorio
    return (leerDocumentos pathFicheros)

leerDocumentos :: [FilePath] -> [Documento]
leerDocumentos [] = []
leerDocumentos (x:xs) = do
                    let documento = unsafePerformIO (leerDocumento x)
                    [documento]++ leerDocumentos xs
leerDocumento :: String -> IO Documento
leerDocumento ruta = do
                putStrLn ruta
                texto <- readFile ruta
                let docuAux = lines texto
                let revista = obtenerRevista docuAux
                let idd = obtenerID docuAux
                let anno = obtenerAnno docuAux
                let titulo = obtenerTitulo docuAux
                let resumen = obtenerResumen docuAux
                let secciones = obtenerSecciones docuAux
                let documento = D (revista,idd,anno,titulo,resumen,secciones)
                return documento

obtenerRevista :: [String] -> String
obtenerRevista [] = []
obtenerRevista texto = head texto

obtenerID:: [String] -> String
obtenerID [] = []
obtenerID texto =  head (drop 1 (texto))

obtenerAnno:: [String] -> String
obtenerAnno [] = []
obtenerAnno texto =  head (drop 2 (texto))

obtenerTitulo:: [String] -> String
obtenerTitulo [] = []
obtenerTitulo texto =  head (drop 4 (texto))

obtenerResumen:: [String] -> String
obtenerResumen [] = []
obtenerResumen texto =  head (drop 6 (texto))

obtenerSecciones :: [String]->[String]
obtenerSecciones [] = []
obtenerSecciones texto = quitarSeparador (drop 8 (texto))

quitarSeparador :: [String] -> [String]
quitarSeparador [] = []
quitarSeparador (s:sn) = if s == "--" || length s <= 1 then --Para quitar lineas blancas
                            quitarSeparador sn
                          else
                            s:quitarSeparador sn
```

and this is the code of my module Documento:

module Documento where

```
data Documento = Documento {revista :: String, idD :: String, anno :: String, titulo :: String, resumen :: String, secciones :: [String]} deriving (Eq)
type Documentos = [Documento]
```

thanks!!

Comment: first please forget for now that `unsafePerfomIO` even exists then use `pathFicheros <- getDirectoryContents directorio` instead of the `let`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue that you are having is that you are trying to call a function which takes in a `[FilePath]`, but you are passing into it an `IO [FilePath]`.

The issue is that the value that you want to pass into the function is encapsulated in the `IO` Monad. A value is held in the `IO` Monad whenever an input/output operation is used to calculate it. In this case, the `IO` Monad is basically saying that some IO was done to create the value, and therefore calling the function that generates the value may not always produce the same output on the same input.

For example, the function `getLines` gets a line of input from the user, and since the line that the user enters cannot be guaranteed to be the same every time, the function returns an `IO String` rather than a regular `String`.

In Haskell, you always want to keep track of when input/output is used. So thus, you generally will not work with functions that take in an IO value and return a non-IO value, as that destroys important context.

Thus, the use of the function `unsafePerformIO :: IO a -> a` is generally discouraged, as it performs an IO action without keeping track of the fact that IO has been performed.

---

That is the theory behind the issue you are facing, now that you know that, you can figure out how to deal with the issue.

When working with IO values, or any other type of monadic values, you need a way to work with the value held within the monad and temporarily ignore the monadic context around the value.

There are a few ways in which this can be done. In your case, you will probably want to work with do notation, since you are already using it a bit.

Let's take a look at the section where you are having issues:

```
reader :: IO [Documento]
reader = do
    setCurrentDirectory "papers"
    directorio <- getCurrentDirectory
    putStrLn directorio       -- Directorio donde estan los documentos
    let pathFicheros = getDirectoryContents directorio
    return (leerDocumentos pathFicheros)
```

Specifically, the error you are getting is with the following lines:

```
let pathFicheros = getDirectoryContents directorio
return (leerDocumentos pathFicheros)
```

The issue is that you are trying to call `leerDocumentos :: [FilePath] -> [Documento]` and pass in `pathFicheros`, which is of type `IO [FIlePath]`, since it is obtained from calling `getDirectoryContents :: FilePath -> IO [FilePath]`.

What you want to do is find a way to work with `pathFicheros` as just a `[FilePath]`, but keep the IO context.

Since you are doing all of this in a do block, you can use the `<-` operator to sort of chuck the IO context up to the do block and assign just the contained value into the constant `pathFicheros`.

```
pathFicheros <- getDirectoryContents directorio
return (leerDocumentos pathFicheros)
```

That way, you can work with `pathFicheros` as a `[FilePath]`, but keep the IO context within the value returned by the `reader :: IO [Documento]` function.

Once you make that change, the code should compile without issue.

However, you will also want to remove your usage of `unsafePerformIO` in `leerDocumentos` and replace it with the proper functionality in the do block, which should then return an `IO [Documento]` instead of just a `[Documento]`. After that you just need to remove the use of `return` at the end of `reader`, leaving in the stuff within the `return`, and you should be good.

I recommend that you do some reading on and experimenting with monads, and common functions work working with monads, such as the "bind" function `>>=`, and that should help you to get a better understanding of how to work with monads such as `IO`.

Monads are a difficult concept to grasp at first in Haskell, but the best thing you can do to get better at working with them is to read up on them and try to implement the ideas you are reading about.